# Как отправить данные формы с помощью Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Совсем только начинаю все это изучать и вот совсем запуталась. Гуглишь, а выдают совершенно разный ответ.
У меня дан select. В нем выбирается город и в соответствии с городом во втором select-е выдается информация по ЦОНам (то есть цоны этого города).
Как отправить на обработку данные. Обрабатывать буду PHP-скриптом.

Comment: Для этих целей post запрос не совсем то и нужен если все это можно из js скрипта подгружать, только вчера смотрел видео на эту тему, в скрипт закидываешь объекты с полями селект и в зависимости от выбранного пункта циклом for in подгружаются html разметка, вот и все -> https://youtu.be/rVpzVbZM-2I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот как-то так это должно выглядеть:

HTML:

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="1">Один</option>
    <option value="2">Два</option>
    <option value="3">Три</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
    <option value="0">Выберите сначала в первом</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select1").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'path/to/php_file',
            data : { select1: $(this).val() },
            success : $("#select2").html
        });
    })
});
```

PHP:

```
for($i=0; $i<$_GET['select1']; $i++){
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'. $_GET['select1'] . " - " . $i ."</option>";
}
```

Comment: <option disabled >Выберите сначала в первом</option>

Comment: option не может так делать, только вот так: <select id="select2" disabled="disabled">, но тогда надо будет расписать success:
...

success: function(data){

    $("#select2").attr("disabled", false).html(data);

}

...

Answer (score 5):

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'path/to/handler',
    data : $('form').serialize(),
    success : function(data) {
        alert(data)
    }
});
```

Comment: стоит отметить, что использование [jQuery][1] существенно упрощает данную процедуру (очень классная штука если кто не знает=) )
[полный мануал по jQuery ajax][2]


  [1]: http://jquery.com/
  [2]: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Кому как, если все что необходимо - работа с ajax, то, лично мне, больше всего нравиться ***[superagent](https://github.com/TooTallNate/superagent)***

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) - почитайте, будет полезно.

[То же самое](http://jquery-docs.ru/ajax/jquery-post/) на русском.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то автор говорит о том, что ему нужно подгружать список вариантов во второй селект в зависимости от первого. А для такой подгрузки POST использовать как-то не к месту.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#form_id").submit()
```