# Как запомнить выбранные файлы в HTML-форме?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть форма с несколькими текстовыми полями и полями для выбора файла. Когда юзер сабмитит форму, на сервере могут быть найдены ошибки в заполнении, тогда он возвращает юзеру страницу, на ней так же есть введенные ним текстовые данные (они приходят с сервера и подсвечиваются если есть ошибка), но как сохранить и выбранные файлы? Что бы ему не пришлось их заново выбирать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте начнем рассматривать вопрос с самого начала.

Система безопасности браузера никогда не скажет какой именно файл был выбран пользователем и тем более не даст вам заполнить форму самостоятельно. Самый просто ответ на ваш вопрос это сказать, что подобное нельзя сделать. Но решения вопроса безусловно существуют и их несколько. Приведу пример наиболее популярных.

**Вариант 1.**
Самый очевидный и наиболее распространенный - это проверить форму пользователя до отправки данных на сервер с помощью Javascript. Причем, с помощью ajax запросов, вы можете проверить и такие данные, как например не является ли Имя пользователя или электронная почта дубликатом уже существующих.

**Вариант 2.** Второй способ отправлять форму [Ajax запросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/130789/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-ajax).

**Вариант 3.** Могу предложить еще один способ. После отправки формы с файлом вы, несмотря на ошибку в форме, загружаете файл и сохраняете его под временным именем. При выводе формы пользователю добавляете cкрытое

```
<input type="hidden" value="out_tmp_file_id">
```

где сохраняете какой-то идентификатор файла созданного на основе одной из хеш функций и если пользователь не указывает новый файл при отправке формы с исправлением ошибки, используете старый идентификатор. А пользователю могу предложить показывать галочку "Загрузить новый файл" для сброса уже загруженного файла. Главное не забыть очищать не востребованные файлы с истекшим сроком годности специальным скриптом.

Comment: @sanu0074, ТС, вы сами сказали, что нужно без аякса и сами же приняли правильным ответом ответ с аяксом в двух вариантах. Очень, очень странно.

Answer (score 0):

Отправлять форму на проверку Ajax-запросом. Подробнее об этом: [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/XMLHttpRequest), [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: нет-нет, без аякса нужно, не указал в топике

Comment: Без аякса никак. По этому-то сейчас 99% форм отправляются и проверяются аяксом без перезагрузок страницы. Сейчас современные браузеры вполне поддерживают даже отправку файлов аяксом. Так что смысла в стандартной отправке формы уже вообще нет.

Answer (score 0):

это не возможно с точки зрения безопасности.
Вы просто отображения имен файлов, выбранных из массиве $ _FILES, но вы не можете установить `<input type="file" value="<?= $_FILES[] ?>"/>` с точки зрения безопасности.

Comment: Вы можете загружать файлы во временный каталог и если форма проходит проверку необходимо переместить их в папку